# Issue with setting up replies in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am in the process of setting up a forum and everything is setup/working well except for my replies are not appearing on the thread "show" page. After checking the rails console, I see they are saving but the user_id and discussion_id are no. The user_id is always nil and the discussion_id is always 0. The discussion threads were easier to setup but with having these replies, I obviously seem to be having an issue. Here are my snippets of code:

```
class PostsController
  # ...

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :set_discussion, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  def create
    @post = @discussion.post.new(create_params) do |post|
      post.user = current_user
    end  
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @discussion, notice: "It has been posted!" 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = @discussion.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    flash.notice = "Deleted"
    redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion)
  end

  private

  def create_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:reply)
  end

  def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

---

```
class DiscussionsController
  def show
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.new
    render :layout => 'discussion'
  end
end
```

Partial rendered to reply:

```
<h2>Reply</h2>

<%= form_for [ @discussion, @post ] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :reply, "Reply" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :reply %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Partial rendered to show replies in on discussion page:

```
<h3><%= post.user.first_name %></h3>
<%= post.reply %>
Posted: <%= post.created_at.strftime("%b. %d %Y") %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete Comment", [post.discussion, post], data: {confirm: "Are you sure you wish to delete?"}, method: :delete, :class => "post_choices" %></p>
```

Just want to mention that I also have the correct associations between the three models (User, Discussion, Post). If there is more code needed, please let me know. I appreciate it very much for any information that may be helpful =)

Joe

**EDIT**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :discussions
  has_many :posts

  # ...
end

class Discussion
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :subject, use: :slugged
end

class Post
  belongs_to :discussion
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I could post the entire user model if needed but its all validations/devise aspects =P The other two I listed all of the contents in the models.

**Edit 2**

Thanks to Max, the user_id returns correctly in the console but still not the discussions. Going go dig around a bit more with the recent changes to see what else =)

Comment: I would check whether `params[:discussion_id]` has a value in the request. It would be good to see the models too, in particular the associations for `discussion` and `user`. Also do you see the `user` of a post that is not a reply?

Comment: I will place the other two models up now. The discussion_id has a value of 0 in the console if that is what you mean? Discussions are the main subject and posts being the reply. Yes, when a discussion is posted, the user information is provided.

Comment: The answer from @adantj is probably your solution (or close). Check that first and then if there are still issues you could add the model data. By the way, could you explain `@users = User.all.order(...)`? It  gets all the users, what for?

Comment: I posted the information you requested. Oh thank you for that reminder =P I had a feature on that page which showed certain users but I have since removed it (and removed that line).

Comment: It looks a bit confusing. A `User` has many `Post`s and many `Discussion`s. Also a `Discussion` has many `Post`s. Are there differences in those *post associations*?

Comment: Hmm...I guess I see what you mean? There is no difference between the two as they are the same model. Is there an aspect I am missing from there?

Comment: These are two different associations. That is a `Post` that is associated with `Discussion` is different from a `Post` associated with `User`. You know what I mean? I think you should review your models.

Comment: A friendly suggestion. When you write out you code examples include the `class Foo` and indent the methods properly. Its a lot cleaner and easier to read. Use one code block per component.

Comment: Sorry, i just want to understand correctly. I would think there is one post that is associated to a discussion and a user. Is that incorrect or do I have it setup incorrectly?

Comment: Will do that next time Max, thank you and I apologize for the messy setup.

Comment: No problem, I edited it for you

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issue you need to deal with.

First you should ensure that Devise is actually authorizing your controller action.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Otherwise `current_user` will return nil if there is no signed in user. And I'm
guessing that you do not want un-authenticated users to be able to create posts.

Also if you have a nested route you most likely want to check that the discussion actually
exists before trying to add posts.

```
class PostsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :set_discussion, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  private

  # Will raise an ActiveRecord::NotFoundError
  # if the Discussion does not exist
  def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When you are creating resources be careful not to query the database needlessly.
This especially applies to `CREATE` and `UPDATE` queries which are expensive.

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params) # INSERT INTO 'users'
  @post.discussion_id = params[:discussion_id]
  @post.user = current_user
  @post.save # UPDATE 'users'
  flash.notice = "It has been posted!"
  redirect_to discussions_path(@post.discussion)
end
```

Also you are not even checking if the record was created successfully.

So lets put it all together:

```
class PostsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :set_discussion, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  def new
    @post = @discussion.post.new
  end

  def create
    # new does not insert the record into the database
    @post = @discussion.post.new(create_params) do |post|
      post.user = current_user
    end  
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @discussion, notice: "It has been posted!" 
    else
      render :new # or redirect back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = @discussion.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    flash.notice = "Deleted"
    redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion)
  end

  private    

  def create_params
    # Only permit the params which the user should actually send!
    params.require(:post).permit(:reply)
  end

  # Will raise an ActiveRecord::NotFoundError
  # if the Discussion does not exist
  def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for all that help! I do have a few questions because while I appreciate the code, I also want to understand it =P I think a lot of my issues are because I originally had customized routes but then realized/was told it's best to use resourceful routes in this case and just nest the posts. 1: With my associations, is it okay to not have a has_many through? I do have a user_id in both post and discussion. 2: I have used before_action: authenticate_user, why before_filter? 3: This throws an issue with the before_filter, which is why I asked =P

Comment: 1. I think you may be better off asking a new question about setting up the relations since it's a bit complex and this is already  a pretty long question.

Comment: 2. `before_filter` and `before_action` actually do the same thing. There is talk of depreciating `before_filter` in Rails 5. I just typed `before_filter` out of habit.

Comment: Fantastic, good to know that, thank you! I really appreciate your help and will look around my code to find what is missing with the discussion_id =P

Comment: Check the url for the form on `/discussions/1` It should be something like `/discussions/1/posts`

Comment: http://localhost:3000/discussions/testing-posts/posts - The URL comes back that way but I do not have a URL set for the form for the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84631/discussion-between-max-and-joe-dayvie).